# 16GB Micro SD Card, but out of space.

Tags: raspbian, storage

I have a 16 GB SD card, but apparently I am already out of space! I ran `ncdu /` and apparently I am only using 2.5 GB. How is this possible? There is no way that the OS (Raspbian) is taking up the remaining 13.5 gigs.

Comment: You can't have expanded the filesysystem to use the full card.  What does df -h report?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It sounds like you have not expanded the install to fill the entire SD card capacity, running `raspi-config` and choosing the "Expand Filesystem" option should do the trick.

Comment: Yes this works. Had a 16gb newly created raspbian card and only had 8% disk space left before expanding the filesystem.